# What do you call a person whose mood is affected by the weather?

Tags: word-request

Macmillan defines:

> **meteoropathy** - a health condition, or symptom caused by certain weather conditions such as humidity, temperature or atmospheric pressure

As I can't find it in any other online vocabulary, I guess it's not a very common word. 
Any other way to say the same in a more colloquial manner? Is there an adjective for it?

Comment: Does your native language have a word for this concept?

Comment: @Sean - I've always regarded _under the weather_ to mean ill or sick, more so than gloomy or depressed.

Comment: That person is caller a **farmer**  :)

Comment: @snailboat - yes, in Italian we say _metereopatico_ quite often

Answer (score 2):

A common term in Canada for when our moods are dictated by the weather is *seasonal depression*. Typically experienced in the winter, *seasonal depression* sums up the sad and gloomy feelings brought on by the weather.

*Seasons depression* is accurate in casual conversation, however it should be noted that it is formally known as *seasonal affective disorder*.

**Seasonal Affective Disorder:**

> A mood disorder subset in which people who have normal mental health throughout most of the year exhibit depressive symptoms at the same time each year, most commonly in the winter. People may sleep too much or have little energy.

Full wikipedia: [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seasonal_affective_disorder)

Comment: Good suggestion, although I think this is more associated with shorter days / longer nights than the weather.

Comment: It is due to lack of sunlight.

Comment: also it the weather being brutally cold doesn't help mood either

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no word in common use for this.  You'd have to describe it.

However we do have an idiom *"as changeable as the weather"* to describe someone who changes (mood) *frequently* and *unpredictably*.  Examples:

> "A woman's heart is **as changeable as the weather** in spring" - Japanese proverb
>
> "Why, what mere children are your fellows of quality; that cry for a plaything one minute, and throw it by the next! -- **as changeable as the weather**, and as uncertain as the stocks."  *The Clandestine Marriage*, George Colman

Answer (score 0):

First, you mention "mood" in your title, but the definition uses the words "a health condition or symptom." So I get the feeling that *meteoropathy* might be used more for joint pain and migraines than irritable moods (although one can often cause the other).

Second, you are right, *meteoropathy* is a little-known and little-used word. Wikipedia lists it under a more common term that might be more recognizable to some: [*weather pains*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weather_pains).

That said, articles such as [this one](http://healthtipsnow.com/meteoropathy/) have a longer list of possible symptoms that fall under the meteorpathy umbrella, including:

> migraines, headaches, dizziness, nausea, fainting, pains in the field of old injuries, rheumatic pains, and muscle aches... fatigue, irritability, mood swings, apathy, lethargy, decreased concentration, coordination and thinking, and sleep disturbances.

I can't think of a common replacement word, though I will say that I've had a few friends who have been known to say things like:

- *My knee is acting up again. Rain must be coming soon*.
- *My back is telling me a thunderstorm is coming.*
- *I'm getting a headache. Makes sense, with this clouds rolling in.*